# Set "Computer" folder to its original view style in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am not sure what I have done, but my "Computer" folder now looks like this:

[image: fig1]

How do I revert it to it's original style, so it looks like this ?

[image: fig2]

I tried:
RMB > Folder options > General > Restore defaults  - nothing
RMB > Folder options > View > Restore defaults  - nothing
View > all options

Edit:
Is there eg. way to reset settings data for that (special) folder ?
Where are the view settings stored for Computer folder ?

Comment: Hold down **Crtl** and scroll the mouse wheel simultaneously to change the view modes.

Comment: @RogUE Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that. Went thru all the options again. Neither one is the right one it seems. : [

Comment: Which part is problematic? Is it the fact that you don't have the pane on the left? The fact that you don't have your drives listed in two columns? Both? (They might be the same setting, I don't know.)

Comment: Default View settings seem to be: Tiles, Sort By: Name & Ascending, Group By: Type & Ascending. Have you tried that particular combination?

Comment: Also, what items are checked in the Choose Details dialog? Default seems to be Name, Type, Total Size, Free Space (put in that order).

Comment: @BrianJ The major part for me is the >advanced< tiles missing. Eg. the Free space bar and info normally displayed at each icon. Though generally I would like to get the whole look back.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yep, I checked the Sort, Group and Details shown settings (on other W7 computer) and tried to set them as you describe. Nothing changed (in the Advanced tiles View type).

Comment: @Riva I'd call attention in your question to the fact that you're missing the Free space bars.  I didn't even notice those until you mentioned it! :-0

Comment: What is "advanced" tiles view type? I don't even have an option named "advanced" anything. It just says Tiles for me. Also, someone else seems to have a similar problem and had to delete registry keys: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/disk-space-usage-bar-in-my-computer-is-missing/457ab86b-54c4-4f11-ac52-49739978ad31.

Comment: @jpmc26 - For some folders Explorer shows "Tiles" for some it shows "Extended tiles" instead. (not "Advanced", sorry)
I thought the "Extended tiles" was some special mode I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the Registry Editor (*regedit*) backup/export the following key first:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
   ```
2. Delete the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
   ```
3. Restart

Note: This will reset all your folder customizations.

Comment: [This guide](https://sites.google.com/site/sysadwonders/journal-blog/operating-systems/microsoft/windows-7/resetwindows7explorerviewfromextendedtilestotiles) says to remove quite a bit more. Dunno whether it’s actually required.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you've hidden the navigation pane. To make it re-appear, try:

"Organize" -> "Layout" -> "Navigation Pane"

Comment: Is that the only difference you see between the images?

Comment: The view has been set to "Medium Icons" instead of "Tiles" as well, but another answer already addressed that. I wasn't sure it was necessary to include.

Comment: Did you read the OP's [comment](http://superuser.com/questions/904256/set-computer-folder-to-its-original-view-style-in-windows-7/904376#comment1213612_904258) on that answer? He says he's already switched between all the views so even if he enables the nav pane the right side will still need to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure then. If their view is already on tiles and it's not showing the free space at the bottom of the drives, they will probably have to go the route you [suggested](http://superuser.com/a/904376/439838) and blow out the key in the registry.

Answer (score 4):

You've set the view to "Medium icons".

To fix:

Right click, View, Tiles

Comment: I'm afraid not. I have View set to "Extended tiles" (top screen is taken with that option selected).
Besides, as I mentioned, I have tried all the View options. Neither sets the folder to the desired style. 
All the options just show plain icons (in various sizes) but none show the tiles with advanced info (free space bar etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If any other folder has the appropriate view (such as your Libraries folder), try going there. While you're in that folder, go to Organize → folder and search options →  View (tab) → Apply to Folders.
Then go back to the Computer window and see if that resolves it.
If it doesn't, try the "Reset Folders" option in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I figured my specific cause and fix.
I remembered I used Disable Autoarrange registry fix [found here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-disable-the-permanent-auto-arrange-setting-in-windows-7-and-8/).
When I reversed the registry change (with undo batch file from the page) my Computer folder settings instantly reversed to its default style (the one I wanted).
When I re-applied the reg fix, the fix works, but Computer folder stayed in the right mode.

So I believe my problem was: I 1st installed the Disable Autoarrange fix, but then I changed >something< in Computer folder settings that broke the folder default behavior.
I honestly have no idea what it was I did. If it should happen again, I'll report it here.

Thanks for all your tips and advices !
I will keep them for a case something will break again irreversibly.

Comment: I am not sure. Should I Accept my own answer ? I used it to solve my problem, but I believe some other answers would solve it too AND are imho more generally applicable ?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click within My Computer and select Group by > Type.

If you have it set to Tile view it will be all back to normal (Default, exactly how it looks in the second picture you posted).